# Rails - Collection_select input showing ID of selection rather then the desired value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, show, nested-forms, collection-select

I have a rails app in which I have a `Project` model, a `Team` model and a `User` model. I am trying to create a nested form within the `Project` **form** using the `Team` model, and in this nested form I have a `collection_select` field which allows the user to select an existing User's email (from the `User` model) and input the data retrieved in a column called `:member` within the `Team` model. So far this is working fine, however the issue im having is that on the **show** page, the data collected from the `collection_select` field is appearing as numbers (the user's ID) instead of the emails that were selected when submitting the form. Why is this happening and how can I fix the issue? Thanks in advance!

project form :-

```
<%= bootstrap_nested_form_for(@project, :html => {:multipart => true}, layout: :horizontal)   do |f| %>

.
.

  <% f.fields_for :teams do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.collection_select :member, User.all, :id, :email, { prompt: "Please select", :selected => params[:user], label: "Employee" } %> 
    <%= builder.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add Team Member", :teams %>


 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Show page:-

```
    <p>
      <strong>Team:</strong>
      <% @project.teams.each do |team| %>
        <%= team.member %>
      <% end %>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry i accidently removed the comment. but the link is http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select and this will work. `<%= builder.collection_select :member, User.all, :email, :email, { prompt: "Please select", :selected => params[:user], label: "Employee" } %>` i think

Comment: it worked thanks alot! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

You will check that third option is the value_method which is saved in table as value. So currently that is `id`. You need to replace that with `email`.

This will work

```
<%= builder.collection_select :member, User.all, :email, :email, { prompt: "Please select", :selected => params[:user], label: "Employee" } %>
```

Comment: I posted another question just now relating to the same part of the application but with a slightly different problem. If it not too much trouble would you mind checking it out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807042/rails-nested-form-data-not-appearing-in-edit-page-despite-showing-in-show