# Rails - Nested form data not appearing in "edit" page despite showing in "show" page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a rails app in which I have a `Project` model, a `Team` model and a `User` model. I am trying to create a nested form within the `Project` **form** using the `Team` model, and in this nested form I have a `collection_select` field which allows the user to select an existing User's email (from the `User` model) and input the data retrieved in a column called `:member` within the `Team` model.

The issue at hand is that that after saving the form, the fields from the nested form appear in the show page, however when I go back to editing the form, the previous entries for the nested form do not appear in the form for me to edit or remove. How can I make the existing form entries appear in the edit page?

project form :-

```
<%= bootstrap_nested_form_for(@project, :html => {:multipart => true}, layout: :horizontal)   do |f| %>

.
.
  <% f.fields_for :teams do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.collection_select :member, User.all, :id, :email, { prompt: "Please select", :selected => params[:user], label: "Employee" } %> 
    <%= builder.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add Team Member", :teams %>


 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Projects controller:-

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
    respond_with(@projects)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@project)
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
    @project.pictures.build
    @project.teams.build
    respond_with(@project)
  end


  def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project.pictures.build
  @project.teams.build
  end

  def create

    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created project."
    redirect_to @project
    else
    render :action => 'new'
    end

  end

  def update
    @project.update(project_params)
    respond_with(@project)
  end

  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    respond_with(@project)
  end

  private
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:id, :title, :description, :status, :phase, :location, :image, pictures_attributes: [:id, :image], teams_attributes: [:project_id, :user_id, :id, :member])
    end
end
```

Comment: will this work. `<%= builder.collection_select :member, User.all, :id, :email, { prompt: "Please select", :selected => @project.teams.try(:map){|s| s.id}, label: "Employee" } %> ` im not sure but try please.

Comment: unfortunately that doesnt seem to be fixing the problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is it by default showing `please select`

Comment: yes. the problem is all the entries I add for the nested fields in the form do not appear in the edit page after submitting the form, so I cant delete them or edit them. I can only keep adding new entries.

Comment: okay first of all please make sure that your your `team.members` are present inside `<% f.fields_for :teams do |builder| %>` block or not. simply try to display them using `<%= @project.teams.try(:map){|s| s.email} %>`inside the fields_for to make sure it is `fields_for` issue or `collection_select`

Comment: After adding that code im now getting a NoMethodError projects#edit: undefined method `email' for #<Team:0x67051b0>

Comment: you need to display `id` instead of email i guess email does not exists for teams

Comment: ok I replaced email with id, and it is listing the id's of the selected user that I previously saved like this: [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]. What can I do now to fix the initial problem?

Comment: actually im not pretty sure about this.. try to making sense of things. will you please try this `<%= builder.collection_select :member, User.all, :id, :email, { :selected => @project.teams.try(:map){|s| s.member}, label: "Employee" } %>`

Comment: just figured out the problem, which is rather embaressing... I had this:   <% f.fields_for :teams do |builder| %> instead of this   <%= f.fields_for :teams do |builder| %> (forgot the = sign).. Thanks for trying to help its much appreciated :)